# How can I get rid of whitespace on the right side of my page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a webpage that I'm trying to design but I'm stuck with persistant whitespace on the right side of the page. I have tried resetting the browser defaults but this has no effect on the page.
I have also tried to make sure that the parent elements all have a declared size but this too has had no impact.

Webpage:

[image]

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  height: 5%;
  background-color: #181818;
}

.siteContainer {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.siteBody {
  height: 100%;
}

.searchArea {
  background-color: #181818;
}

.resultArea {
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container siteContainer">
  <div class="row navbar">
    <div class="col col-2 ">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="col col-10 ">
      Navbar
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row siteBody">
    <div class="col col-2 searchArea">
      Search and CRUD
    </div>
    <div class="col col-10 resultArea">
      Results
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please update the question with proper library import and making the issue reproucible in fiddle

Comment: I see `max-width: 1320px;` so that might be it. Bootstrap does not fill the page

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/: _"Bootstrap comes with three different containers: `.container`, **which sets a max-width at each responsive breakpoint**; `.container-fluid`, which is width: 100% at all breakpoints; ..."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youre using bootstraps `container` class which has fixed max widths (see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/layout/containers/).

What you want it `container-fluid` which fills 100% of the page.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.navbar {
  height: 5%;
  background-color: #181818;
}

.siteContainer {
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.siteBody {
  height: 100%;
}

.searchArea {
  background-color: #181818;
}

.resultArea {
  background-color: #121212;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid siteContainer">
  <div class="row navbar">
    <div class="col col-2 ">
      Logo
    </div>
    <div class="col col-10 ">
      Navbar
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row siteBody">
    <div class="col col-2 searchArea">
      Search and CRUD
    </div>
    <div class="col col-10 resultArea">
      Results
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```